# Half yearly sum display

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Using Oracle i want to write a query which display sum of first and second half year data.

If my data search condition like 2016/02 ~ 2017/12.

I want to display result like below.
1.Sum of price from 2016/01/01 ~ 2016/06/30 - First half year row
2.Sum of price from 2016/07/01 ~ 2016/12/31 - Second half year row
3.Sum of price from 2017/01/01 ~ 2017/06/30 - First half year row
4.Sum of price from 2017/07/01 ~ 2017/12/31 - Second half year row

Comment: `2016/13/31` .  . ?

Comment: sorry and thankx...updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the format model `'Q'` to fetch the quarter of year. And manipulate it to calculate half yearly, like below.

```
TO_CHAR(day,'YYYY')|| (CASE WHEN(TO_CHAR(day,'Q')<=2) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
```

Full Query will be like

```
 SELECT  TO_CHAR(day,'YYYY')|| (CASE WHEN(TO_CHAR(day,'Q')<=2) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), 
         SUM( price) 
 from my_data
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(day,'YYYY')|| (CASE WHEN(TO_CHAR(day,'Q')<=2) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
ORDER BY 1
```

Sample Output:

```
20161   62700
20162   4095
20171   163075
20172   36945
```